# Jquery autocomplete suggestion is not showing under textbox 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have been trying to get a simple example of the jquery-ui autocomplete to work. I have a controller setup to handle the query, and it returns the string that looks to be in order, but I am getting no suggestions showing up.

Here are the  libraries I am including on that page

```
<link href="/Content/css/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/css/Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/css/coupon1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/Slider/slidder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/el7r_notify.min.jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.spellcheck.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/Slider/jquery.jcarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/Slider/jquery-func.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Coupon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and here is the javascript and the form tags:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/GetCompanyNames',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        response($.map(msg));
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });



    <div class="ui-widget"> 
  <label for="tags">tags: </label> 
   <input id="tags" /> 
</div>
```

I get back a string response that looks reasonable from my controller:

"LTJRKK,
KTOYQQ,
GDADKT,
PVFOQT,
PVFOQT,
YNKYVS,
YNKYVS,
DQBOVU,
DQBOVU
"

this string seem to be the default naming that autocomplete is looking for.

But I get no joy at all. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does jQuery custom min include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map) is incorrect. You are not supplying the callback function to `$.map`, which is probably causing the problem.

In this case, you do not need to use `$.map` at all since your action returns data in the correct format. The following should work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: '/Home/GetCompanyNames'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need this:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "url",
      data: request,
      dataType: "json",
      method: "post",
      success: response
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: First of all it contains error at third last line that you forgot to write `);` and after that i tried it but its not working